# Use Apache .htaccess to allow request if variable is presented

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I need to hide the site from guest users and show it just if **preview** variable is presented or the user is in **wp-admin** folder.

Now in .htaccess I have

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule (.*)/wp-admin(.*) - [QSA,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-admin [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteRule . / [L]
```

It works well for the task condition. I need to check if there is a **preview** GET parameter is presented and allow such request to be handled by index.php. The request can look like

```
    http://domain.com/about/?preview_id=152&preview_nonce=657d480c2c&preview=true
```

Of course if **preview** variable exists all assets should be handled in a normal way.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more `RewriteCond` for `preview` parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*)/wp-admin(.*) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

# rest of the rules
```

Comment: Typo in preview:  perview

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. Even with correct variable name.

Comment: Is `http://domain.com/about/?preview_id=152&preview_nonce=657d480c2c&preview=true` still going to `domain.com/` after corrected rule?

Comment: Yes, the request is the same.

Comment: Yes but `doesn't work` can mean anything? What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry. I get 404. I think I should direct server to index.php after all.

Comment: Right `404` means rule is working fine and not forcing `preview` URL to landing page. You should have regular front controller rule of WP after above rules anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112158/discussion-between-maks-sherstobitow-and-anubhava).